# How to print multiple instances of QTextBrowser into one PDF file?

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qtextbrowser

the QT application I'm working on comes with a tutorial. Each chapter is a stand-alone HTML file, each file can span multiple pages. Now I want to print them into one single PDF file (with page numbers).

My naive approach was this, but it's wrong:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QPrinter printer;
  printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
  printer.setOutputFileName("/tmp/test.pdf");

  QTextBrowser *tp = new QTextBrowser();

  tp->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///help/tutorial_item_1.html"));
  tp->print(&printer);

  tp->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///help/tutorial_item_2.html"));
  tp->print(&printer);

  tp->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///help/tutorial_item_3.html"));
  tp->print(&printer);

  // etc...
}
```

However, this will restart the printer on each `print()` call, starting with a new PDF file, overwriting the old one.

What is a simple solution to print all HTML into one PDF file, using QT?

Comment: You may unite content of two text browsers and print them in one step

Comment: try with `printer.newPage()` after each print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developping on your "naive approach", I could print concatenated html files by appending several pages to a parent `QTextEdit`. It would probably also work utilizing a second `QTextBrowser` instead.

```
  // ...
  QTextBrowser *tp = new QTextBrowser();
  QTextEdit te;

  tp->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///help/tutorial_item_1.html"));
  te.append(tp->toHtml());

  tp->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///help/tutorial_item_2.html"));
  te.append(tp->toHtml());

  te.print(&printer);

  // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by rendering your contents on a [QPainter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) object linked to the [QPrinter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) device

```
// Sample code ahead ~>
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("C:\\test.pdf");
printer.setFullPage(true);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
QTextBrowser tb;

QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&printer);

QRect rect = printer.pageRect();
tb.resize(rect.width(), rect.height());

{
  QFile file("C:\\test1.html");
  if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QTextStream ts(&file);
    tb.setHtml(ts.readAll());
    file.close();
    tb.render(&painter, QPoint(0,0));
  }
}

if(printer.newPage() == false)
  qDebug() << "ERROR";

{
  QFile file("C:\\test2.html");
  if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    QTextStream ts(&file);
    tb.setHtml(ts.readAll());
    file.close();
    tb.render(&painter, QPoint(0,0));
  }
}
painter.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it doesn't help in my case, `tb.render()` does not handle multi-page HTML content.